# uniqueness of quotients of principal congruence subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

For each $n \geq 2$, is $\Gamma(2^{n})$ the unique normal subgroup of $\Gamma(2)$ with quotient isomorphic to $\Gamma(2) / \Gamma(2^{n})$ (here we are talking about principal congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$)?  I can show this using elementary group theory for up to $n = 3$ and suspect there's a group theoretic argument that would prove it for all $n$.

Comment: Isn't $\Gamma(2)$ (in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$) a free group?

Comment: Yes, and $\Gamma(2) \lhd \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the direct product of a free group and $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: So then I don't see how what you want can possibly be true.  Any 2-generated finite group $Q$ will have many epimorphisms $\Gamma(2)\to Q$ (one for each generating pair), and the kernels will be different unless they differ by an automorphism of $Q$. (Unless the groups $\Gamma(2)/\Gamma(2^n)$ have the very special property that every generating pair differs by an automorphism.)

Comment: It can be proven true for $\Gamma(8)$, using a nice presentation of $\Gamma(2) / \Gamma(8)$ from which it's apparent that any pair of generators satisfies these relations.  I suspect that with some effort, I would find that it's true for $\Gamma(16)$ etc. in the same way, but I hoped there was some variant of that argument that would work for all $n$ (or that maybe it would be known by some other argument).

Comment: @HJRW I wonder what the structure of the quotient is (it is of order $2^{3 (n-1)},$ so is nilpotent, but what else. Maybe I will ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I notice (from an answer to another MathOverflow question, which links to http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-03/S0002-9947-1951-0043847-X/S0002-9947-1951-0043847-X.pdf) that each $\Gamma(2^{n})$ is characteristic in $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.  I wonder if this can be used to get what I want.